# Problem with RabbitMQ and deduplication plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I'm a RabbitMQ newbie; for a new project I need to use the deduplication plugin. I'm using AspNet Core 3.0 worker process and language is C#.

I've tried a very simple example, 2 publishers sending 10 messages numbered 1 to 10 and one consumer getting messages and acknowledging them.

I'm having quite strange and unpredictable results:

if I run the 3 workers (2 Publishers and one consumer) inside the same process, it looks like that deduplication plugin works fine and inserts in the queue only 10 unique messages, but the consumer reads only the first 2 and ackowledges only one of them.

if I run publishers and consumer in two different processes, the consumer gets all the 10 messages but after ack the messages remain in the queue and if I run again the consumer process they get reprocessed again.

I've tried to google for some full working sample in C# for deduplication, but without success

Publisher

```
        int cnt = 1;
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dd = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dd["x-message-deduplication"] = true;
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: qname,
                                 durable: true,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: dd);

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = GetMessage(cnt);
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.Persistent = true;
                Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                d["x-deduplication-header"] = cnt;
                properties.Headers = d;

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                     routingKey: qname,
                                     basicProperties: properties,
                                     body: body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);

                logDB(cnt, "Sender"+Wname);
                cnt++;
                if (cnt > 10)
                    break;
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
```

Consumer:

```
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> dd = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                dd["x-message-deduplication"] = true;
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: qname,
                                     durable: true,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: dd);

                _logger.LogInformation("{0} Waiting for messages.", Cname);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    _logger.LogInformation("{0} Received {1}", Cname, message);


                    string[] parts = message.Split('-');
                    int cntmsg = int.Parse(parts[1]);

                    logDB(cntmsg, Cname);

                    Thread.Sleep((cntmsg % 5) * 1000);


                    _logger.LogInformation("{0} Received {1} done", Cname, message);

                    channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: true);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: qname,
                                     autoAck: false,
                                     consumer: consumer);

                _logger.LogInformation("{0} After BasicConsume", Cname);

                while (true)
                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);

            }
```

Comment: I am confused about how this plugin do for `requeued` message. I perfer `Exchange level deduplication` to `Queue level deduplication`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try using exchange... do you have a full working sample I could start with?

Answer (score 2):

after contacting the developer of the deduplication plugin it turned out the problem was related to the type (int) of deduplication header, using a string value works.

He will release a new version supporting int datatype soon.